# Kafka consumers unable to keep pace on some brokers, not others

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic with 6 partitions spread over 3 brokers (ie 2 partitions per broker).

I have consumers on 6 separate worker nodes (using Storm).

The partitions are all accepting 20MB/s of messages.

2 partitions are able to output 20MB/s to the consumers on 2 nodes but the other 2 are only managing ~15 MB/s.

File cache is working properly and there are no direct disk reads on any broker.

The offset tracking for the partitions is done by the consumer (ie manualPartitionAssignment, nothing committed to Kafka nor Zookeeper).

What could be causing the apparent internal latency on 2 of the brokers for 4 of the partitions? The load profile, GC etc seems similar across all 3 brokers' JVMs. I am monitoring all manner of metrics for the fetch consumer operation etc through the JMX Mbeans but can't figure this out. Any pointers?

Comment: what about the replication latency ? if you enabled it

Comment: Nope. No replication on this topic. Thanks for the suggestion. The only replication is on the default consumer_offsets topic, which we're not using, of course.